# Share response object nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback

I've the following code that sends an page.html or any other html file in node.  I'm using a lot of nesting(sample 1), if i don't use it and use named functions(sample 2), i've to declare variables to hold response, is there a better but simple alternative like bind or any other strategy ?

```
// Sample 1
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(); 
server.on("request",requestHandler);

server.listen(8080);

function requestHandler(request,response){

    var regPageName = /(\w+\.\w+)+$/;

    var urlRequested = request.url;
    var match = regPageName.exec(urlRequested);

    if(match!=null){
        var fileName = match[1]; // first capture group is filename

        // check for existence of file
        fs.exists(fileName,function(doesExist){
            if(doesExist){
                // file exists dump it now
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        fs.readFile(fileName,function(err,data){
          if(err){
            throw err;
          }
          else{
            response.write(data.toString());
            response.end();
          }
        }); // readfile
            }// exists
            else{
                response.writeHead(404,'Not Found');
                response.end();
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(400,'Bad Request');
        response.end();
    }


}
```

And here is sample 2

```
// Sample 2
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var glrequest;
var glresponse;
var glfilename ;
var server = http.createServer(); 
server.on("request",requestHandler);

server.listen(8080);

function requestHandler(request,response){
  glrequest = request;
  glresponse = response;
    var regPageName = /(\w+\.\w+)+$/;

    var urlRequested = request.url;
    var match = regPageName.exec(urlRequested);

    if(match!=null){
        var fileName = match[1]; // first capture group is filename
        glfilename = fileName;
        // check for existence of file
        fs.exists(fileName,CheckExistence);
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(400,'Bad Request');
    response.end();
    }
}// requestHandler

function CheckExistence(doesExist){
  if(doesExist){
    // file exists dump it now
    glresponse.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});

    fs.readFile(glfilename,dumpData); // readfile
  }// exists
  else{
    glresponse.writeHead(404,'Not Found');
    glresponse.end();
  }
}

function dumpData(err,data){
  if(err){
    glresponse.end();
    throw err;
  }
  else{
    glresponse.write(data.toString());
    glresponse.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can pass `response` to your functions as a parameter.

Comment: BTW, the node.js documentation recommends you avoid `fs.exists()`: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: Thanks, i read it.  I usually use this technique of checking if a file exists in c# before reading it so as to avoid exception handling code..If node is the only process on the server, ( and since its single threaded) the chance of another process deleting it is rare..but i really appreciate you're suggestion thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to pass the local variable to the named function is to wrap it in an anonymous function (or a local function in the same scope as the variable). Eg:

```
        fs.exists(fileName,function(exists) { CheckExistence(exists, filename); );
    ...
    function CheckExistence(doesExist, filename){
        if(doesExist){
        ...
```

As mentioned in my comment, use of `fs.exists()` is discouraged in the Node.js doc.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man, i was able to do it using anonymous functions.. wonder if there is a promise/a+ way to do it..but to be honest, i'd rather not promise using promises :)

Comment: @Bharat: You are probably right, promises seem to make callbacks neater. This is likely to make the code cleaner, provided you are familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented suggestions by [fd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13956/fd) and came up with the following resolution.  Improvements are welcome :)

```
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(); 
server.on("request",requestHandler);

server.listen(8080);
//1
function requestHandler(request,response){
    var regPageName = /(\w+\.\w+)+$/;

    var urlRequested = request.url;
    var match = regPageName.exec(urlRequested);

    if(match!=null){
        var fileName = match[1]; // first capture group is filename
        // check for existence of file
        fs.exists(fileName,function(doesExist){
      CheckExistence(doesExist,fileName,response);}
    );
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(400,'Bad Request');
    response.end();
    }
}// requestHandler
//1.1
function CheckExistence(doesExist,fileName,response){
  if(doesExist){
    // file exists dump it now
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.readFile(fileName,
      function(err,data){
      dumpData(err,data,response);}
    ); // readfile
  }// exists
  else{
    response.writeHead(404,'Not Found');
    response.end();
  }
}
//1.1.1
function dumpData(err,data,response){
  if(err){
    response.end();
    throw err;
  }
  else{
    response.write(data.toString());
    response.end();
  }
}
```